# Forms information transfer to PDF in php

Tags: php, forms, pdf

I am building a site that allows my client for keying in their information, the information will be automatically going to my PDF forms (many other forms). Thus, the users do not have to fill up every time.
Is it possible to do that with the use of PHP?

e.g. forms fill in our site and the data goes to the pdf file. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php?rq=1

Comment: How do you get your data to the PDF form? Do you have something in place, or is that what you are asking?

Comment: You need some form of persistent storage for the data, typically a simple database is used. That certainly is possible by means of php, sure.

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem that i am having now